# Degree of freedom in a system of inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of inequalities of the form

$Ax<=b$

where the unknowns $(x_1, x_2,..., x_m)$ outnumber the inequalities $(n)$. I know that in the worst case scenario $k$ inequalities become binding. Thus, the degree of freedom is $(m-k)$.

Is is possible to keep the first $k$ variables $x_1, ..., x_k$ and allocate any value to the remaining $(m-k)$ variables $x_{k+1},...,x_m$ freely? In other words, is it possible to assume that $x_1,..., x_k$ take care of the binding inequalities and the remaining decision variables $x_{k+1},...,x_m$ are free to vary within their limits with no limitation? Is there any proof for this?

Thanks!